# Darknet error after 100 iterations on YOLOv4-tiny [Windows OS]

Tags: python, darknet, yolov4

Can anyone help me with Darknet? I am following a youtube tutorial but there's no error on their side. The code gives this error after 1000 iterations:

> Saving weights to
> mydrive/yolov4-tiny/training/yolov4-tiny-custom_last.weights Couldn't
> open file: /mydrive/yolov4-tiny/training/yolov4-tiny-custom_last.weights

Since I am running locally, I can't run this command:

> !ln -s
> C:\Users\Pinky\Desktop\ /mydrive

Any idea on how to fix this? I am using my own dataset btw.

Answer (score -1):

Usually it the training can be crushed after certain number of iteration due to the dataset. Check badlist file in the darknet folder and you might get a list of images which are creating the error. You need to delete those specific images with their annotation files from the image folder

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).